# Ansible: how to change/replace a port number in a configuration file

Tags: regex, ansible, regex-replace

I am a newbie in the ansible world and one of the first thing I want to do is to change the default port in a configuration file: `/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini`

Every time where value `3389` is found, I would like to replace it by a new value given by the variable `xrdp_port`

```
vars:
  xrdp_port: 3391
```

I thought that something like the following declaration would work but unfortunately it doesn't

```
    - name: tune /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini
      replace:
        path: "/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini"
        regexp: '(.*)3389(.*)'
        replace: '\1{{ xrdp_port }}\2'
```

I would strongly appreciate any help
Thank you

Comment: The limitation of replacing '3389' only doesn't make sense. '3389' is the [default](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-xrdp.ini/). No 'port' configuration or 'port=3389' is the same. It would make sense to add 'port={{ xrdp_port }}' always.

Answer (score 1):

Q: **"*Where value 3389 is found replace it with a new value given by the variable xrdp_port.*"**

A: Given the file [xrdp.ini](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-xrdp.ini/) for testing

```
shell> cat xrdp.ini
port=3389
```

the task below does the job

```yaml
    - replace:
        path: xrdp.ini
        regexp: '^(\s*)port(\s*)=(\s*)3389(\s*?)$'
        replace: '\1port={{ xrdp_port }}'
      vars:
        xrdp_port: 3391
```

Running the play with options *--check --diff* will display the difference

```yaml
TASK [replace] ********************************************************
--- before: xrdp.ini
+++ after: xrdp.ini
@@ -1 +1 @@
-port=3389
+port=3391

changed: [localhost]
```

When the port is not set to default

```
shell> cat xrdp.ini
port=3999
```

the task will do nothing

```yaml
TASK [replace] *****************************************************
ok: [localhost]
```

---

But, the limitation of replacing '3389' only doesn't make sense. '3389' is the default. No 'port' configuration or 'port=3389' is the same. It would make sense to add 'port={{ xrdp_port }}' always, e.g.

```yaml
    - replace:
        path: xrdp.ini
        regexp: '^(\s*)port(\s*)=(.*?)$'
        replace: '\1port={{ xrdp_port }}'
      vars:
        xrdp_port: 3391
```

will replace any port's value by the value of *xrdp_port*

```yaml
TASK [replace] *****************************************************
--- before: xrdp.ini
+++ after: xrdp.ini
@@ -1 +1 @@
-port=3999
+port=3391

changed: [localhost]
```

---

But, the line won't be added if the 'port' option is missing, e.g.

```
shell> cat xrdp.ini
security_layer=tls
```

the task will do nothing

```yaml
TASK [replace] *****************************************************
ok: [localhost]
```

It would be better to use the module [*lineinfile*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#ansible-builtin-lineinfile-manage-lines-in-text-files) instead of *replace*, e.g.

```yaml
    - lineinfile:
        path: xrdp.ini
        regexp: '^(\s*)port(\s*)=(.*)$'
        line: 'port={{ xrdp_port }}'
      vars:
        xrdp_port: 3391
```

will add the line

```yaml
TASK [lineinfile] **************************************************
--- before: xrdp.ini (content)
+++ after: xrdp.ini (content)
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 security_layer=tls
+port=3391

changed: [localhost]
```

If the option 'port' is present in the file the same task will also  replace any port's value by the value of xrdp_port

```
shell> cat xrdp.ini
port=3999
```

```yaml
TASK [lineinfile] **************************************************
--- before: xrdp.ini (content)
+++ after: xrdp.ini (content)
@@ -1 +1 @@
-port=3999
+port=3391

changed: [localhost]
```